# why google recaptcha is not showing up?

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

I using google recaptcha, my form is too simple, it will just display the google recaptcha, but its not displayed, there are no errors appeared, I can't understand what is the problem, here is my code:

```
<html>

    <body>

        <form method="post" action="contact.php">
            <?php  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
                  $publickey = "6Ld72voSAAAAADku3vUoC712Zo8jUmjHJS8N77Ym"; // you got this from the signup page
                  echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
             ?>
        </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: @AdamSinclair recaptcha lib is exist, and I am sure that I am using the right public key

Comment: Have you verified you're able to see error messages if they happen? (This simplest way is to generate one yourself, such as `echo $does_no_exist;`.)

Comment: You might want to add this for debugging `error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`

Comment: suddenly I removed the comment that written to right of the public key, now recpatcha is showing !!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question. But answering if it might help someone.

If your captcha code is using some other server, try changing it to following.

```
define("RECAPTCHA_API_SERVER", "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api");
define("RECAPTCHA_API_SECURE_SERVER", "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api");
define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", "www.google.com");
```

It resolved Captcha Display issues for me :)